# Bash script skip mounting Extended partition

Tags: bash, disk-partitioning

I created the following script, but it hangs if there are extended partitions on the system. Mount tries to mount the extended partition witch of course does not work.

How do I remove a partition from the loop if a partition is extended???

```
for i in hda hdb hdc hdd hde hdf sda sdb sdc sdd sde sdf sdg sdh sdi ; do 
fdisk -l /dev/$i > /tmp/mnt.txt 
cat /tmp/mnt.txt | grep "Disk" 1>/dev/null && { echo -n "controle harddisk $i: "
found=0
for j in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ; do
cat /tmp/mnt.txt | grep "$i$j" 1>/dev/null && { echo -n "$i$j " ; 
    found="1"; 
    mkdir /media/$i$j 2>/dev/null
    mount /dev/$i$j /media/$i$j 2>/dev/null

        # test voor /C
    if [ -d "/media/$i$j/Program Files" ] ; then
        umount /media/$i$j 
        mount /dev/$i$j /C 
        echo -n "(/C) " 
    fi

        # test voor /B
    if [ -d /media/$i$j/Boot ] ; then 
        umount /media/$i$j 
        mount /dev/$i$j /B 
        echo -n "(/B) " 
    fi

        # test voor /herstel
    if [ -f /media/$i$j/partimage ] || [ -f /media/$i$j/fsarchiver ] || [ -d /media/$i$j/lost+found ] ; then
        umount /media/$i$j 
        mount /dev/$i$j /herstel 
        echo -n "(/herstel) "  
    fi

        # test voor /G
    if [ -d /media/$i$j/herstel ] ; then
        umount /media/$i$j 
        mount /dev/$i$j /G
        echo -n "(/G) "
        fi
}
done
if [ "$found" == "0"  ] ; then echo "(geen partities)"; else echo ""; fi
}
```

done
df

Answer (score 1):

To narrowly answer your question, you probably simply want to add another `grep -v "Linux extended"` to your second `grep` invocation - this should filter out lines that contain extended permissions.

Depending on where you intend to run this and how widely you want to distribute it, I'd also suggest thinking about the design and adding a more "positive" match criterion (e.g. only mounting partitions that are of a given type, not specifically excluding those that don't (e.g. what about swap partitions in your example?), which will be much safer approach.

Comment: Just had a lightbulb hanging above my head. Added: sed -i '/Extended/d' /tmp/mnt.txt. Now all the lines with "Extended" are deleted. The script is only used on windows machines.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood good, extended means logical partition, like in this image (is sda2)

http://s1053.photobucket.com/user/curious_apprentice/media/ApplyingWindowsdrivereziseactiononGparted.png.html

I usually do by checking for size in /sys/class/block/sd$i$j/size
if it's greater than  100  means it's non logical partition

```
if [ `cat /sys/class/block/sd$i$j/size` -gt 100 ]; then

  echo "sd$i$j it's extended"

fi
```

:)
Adonay